# Find highest/lowest value by the data of two different tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am newbie and I need help with Database of an Ad/Marketing agency

I have two tables, one is **List_of_billboards** that has three columns: Billboard_ID(PK), Location and Type and the second one is **Billboard_Ad_Campaigns** which has four columns: Ad_ID(PK), Cost_of_campaign, ID_of_client, Billboard_ID (FK).

Data of the tables look like:

Table1:

```
Billboard_ID | Location     |  Type
BbID001      |    London    |  Digital
BbID002      |    Hayward   |  3D
BbID003      |    Las Vegas |  Painted
BbID004      |    New York  |  Painted
```

Table2:

```
Ad_ID   |  Cost_of_campaign | ID_of_client | Billboard_ID
BbCID0001    $123               001            BbID001       
BbCID0002    $456               002            BbID002       
BbCID0003    $789               003            BbID003       
BbCID0004    $1234              003            BbID004
```

How do I find highest/lowest cost of a certain type of Billboard (3D, Digital, Painted, etc.)?

For example, according to the above data, painted billboard with highest cost would be the BbID004 (New York one)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
This isn't a free code writing service.
Neither is it a replacement for tutorials or web searches.
Please read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and add the code you've tried so far. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?
Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.type,
       max(t2.cost_of_campaign) max_cost_of_campaign,
       min(t2.cost_of_campaign) min_cost_of_campaign
from table1 t1 
join table2 t2
on t1.Billboard_ID = t2.Billboard_ID
group by t1.type
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5abc548aa178a82a9f6f33527fa5c265

or if need others columns from max and min get with windowed functions and first_value

```
select distinct t1.type,
       first_value(t1.Billboard_ID) over (partition by t1.type order by t2.cost_of_campaign desc) max_Billboard_ID,
       max(t2.cost_of_campaign) over (partition by t1.type) max_cost_of_campaign,
       first_value(t1.Billboard_ID) over (partition by t1.type order by t2.cost_of_campaign asc) min_Billboard_ID,
       min(t2.cost_of_campaign) over (partition by t1.type) min_cost_of_campaign
from table1 t1 
join table2 t2
on t1.Billboard_ID = t2.Billboard_ID
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=887b95cb041b1d6fb37ccfb47aabd3ea

Answer (score 2):

Use window functions.  For the least expensive campaign:

```
select b.*
from (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.type order by t2.cost_of_campaign asc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1 join
           table2 t2
           on t1.Billboard_ID = t2.Billboard_ID
     ) b
where seqnum = 1
```